3D Collision detection between two objects in Javascript
I am trying to build a 3d game engine, and with it comes a 3d collision system to check whether an object intersects with another. I've tried implementing a function to check for collision however, the box does not move and does not produce any positive results.
so far I've tried the following function

        function collision(pt1, pt2) {
            return !((pt1.x > pt2.x + pt2.w) || (pt1.x + pt1.w < pt2.x) || (pt1.y > pt2.y + pt2.h) || ( pt1.y + pt1.h < pt2.y) || (pt1.z > pt2.z + pt2.d) || (pt1.z + pt1.d < pt2.z));
        }

the point arrays are as follows:
class Plane {
            constructor(x,y,z,w,h,d) {
                this.x=x;
                this.y=y;
                this.z=z;
                this.w=w;
                this.h=h;
                this.d=d;

                this.points = [new point(this.x - this.w, this.y-this.h, this.z+this.d),
                            new point(this.x + this.w, this.y-this.h, this.z+this.d),
                            new point(this.x + this.w, this.y+this.h, this.z+this.d),
                            new point(this.x - this.w, this.y+this.h, this.z+this.d),
                            new point(this.x - this.w, this.y-this.h, this.z-this.d),
                            new point(this.x + this.w, this.y-this.h, this.z-this.d),
                            new point(this.x + this.w, this.y+this.h, this.z-this.d),
                            new point(this.x - this.w, this.y+this.h, this.z-this.d)];

I've created two objects to check whether they intersect with one another as follows:
    var plane1 = new Plane(w/2-300, h/2-300, 100, 100,10,100);
    var box1 = new Plane(w/2-300, h/2, 90, 10,10,10);

Checking the collision logic below. It checks whether the box is above the plane, as long as this is true the box will descent accordingly:
 for(let i =0; i<box1.points.length; i++) {
                for(let j = 0; j<plane1.points.length; j++) {
                    if(collision(box1.points[i],plane1.points[j])) {
                        console.log("----");
                    }
                    else {
                        box1.points[i].y -= 1;
                    }
                }
            }

The box simply doesn't move, perhaps its due to the collision function implemented. Can someone check for me and ensure I've carried out the collision system correctly?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

So, box doesn’t move or not hitting? Could you make codepen with this problem?
